# python - find where modules are stored in Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyzo

I installed some modules such as matplotlib, through both the methods:

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

and

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Technically I should have the library somewhere, right?
But I don't know where. Looking at the /usr/lib/python..., I have found the folders python2.7, python3, python3.6, python3.7.

I am using the IDE Pyzo, and I can choose whether to use python2.7 and python3.6. But neither of those find the module. So, it gives me the option to add a path to tell the software where to find the modules, but I don't know what path to write.

How can I understand where have the modules been installed, or where to find the modules?

Comment: In general, if the module is importable for you, you should be able to do: `python -c "import modulename; print(modulename.__file__)"` and learn about it's whereabouts. :) Replace `modulename` with the module you're interested in. You can also run those two commands from your interpreter interactive session of course.

Comment: thanks @OndrejK.! The code has worked as intended, and I have found the path. But even if I add that path to my pythonPath, the software doesn't work. If I try from the terminal by running "python myfile.ly", I get an awful "username request"